# Must path parameters always come at the end of the URL?

Tags: url, path, uri

Is this URL valid?

```
/path_A?param=value/path_B/path_C
```

after the parameters, there are more stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that URL is valid, but it probably won't be parsed the way you want.

- The path is `/path_A`
- The query string is `param=value/path_B/path_C`
- The value of `param` is `value/path_B/path_C`

Comment: What scenario would there be a use for such a URL?

Comment: It's your example.  I thought you must have a use case in mind.

Comment: If you submitted `<form method=GET action=/path_A><input type=text name=param value=value/path_B/path_C></form>` would result in that URL.